# Preenchimento e importação de dados com VBA no excel, ajuda em código?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Olá, a situação que estou tentando automatizar no excel, através do VBA é a seguinte: Possuo duas planilhas (Arquivos do excel diferentes), onde os dois possuem o mesmo cabeçalho (com informações como ID, Nome, Descrição...), porém com as colunas em ordem diferente (na planilha 1, Nome é a coluna C, e na planilha 2, Nome é a coluna F, por exemplo). Em uma dessas planilhas, o conteúdo esta preenchido e na outra há somente o cabeçalho, por isso criei um botão em VBA na planilha em que há somente o cabeçalho, para que ele busque as informações correspondentes a cada coluna do cabeçalho e importe os dados (copie e cole), de forma automática. O código que criei é o seguinte, e esta dando erro, referente a objeto :

```
Sub Botão4_Clique()

    Dim contador, col As Integer
    Dim valor, PastaAtual, NomeDoArquivo, NomeCompletoDoArquivo As String
    Dim Busca As Range

    contador = 0
    col = 1

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1").Activate


    Do While Cells(1, col).Value <> ""

        Cells(1, col).Select
        valor = Cells(1, col).Value


        PastaAtual = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
        NomeDoArquivo = "teste.xlsx"
        NomeCompletoDoArquivo = PastaAtual + "\" + NomeDoArquivo
        Workbooks.Open (NomeCompletoDoArquivo)

        Set Busca = Cells.Find(What:=valor, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1").Activate
        Cells(1, col).Activate
        Set tbl = ActiveCell
        tbl.Offset(1, 0).Resize(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, tbl.Columns.Count).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=0).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Workbooks(NomeCompletoDoArquivo).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False


        contador = contador + 1
       col = col + 1
    Loop


MsgBox contador


End Sub
```

O que pode estar errado ? Obrigada

Comment: * Desculpe, o botão esta na realidade na planilha em que os dados estão preenchidos.

Comment: "[...] e esta dando erro, referente a objeto". Em qual linha?

Comment: No comando "Find", em Set Busca = Cells.Find(What:=valor, ...

Answer (score 1):

O Trecho parece incorreto:

```
 Set Busca = Cells.Find(What:=valor, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Conforme https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837085.aspx `Range.Activate` é um método e como tal ele não espera retornar um valor `Range` para Busca mas sim um `Variant`

Além disso tem outros erros. Proponho o seguinte:

```
Sub Importa()

Dim contador, col As Integer
Dim valor, PastaAtual, NomeDoArquivo, NomeCompletoDoArquivo As String
Dim Busca As Range
Dim RangeFrom As Range
Dim RangeTo As Range
Dim Busca_col As Integer
Dim WorkBookNovo As Workbook

contador = 0
col = 1


ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1").Activate
PastaAtual = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
NomeDoArquivo = "Pasta2.xlsx"
NomeCompletoDoArquivo = PastaAtual + "\" + NomeDoArquivo
Set WorkBookNovo = Workbooks.Open(NomeCompletoDoArquivo)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1").Activate

Do While Cells(1, col).Value <> ""

    Cells(1, col).Select
    valor = Cells(1, col).Value

    Columns(col).Select
    numRows = Selection.Rows.Count
    Selection.Resize(numRows - 1).Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Set RangeFrom = Selection

    WorkBookNovo.Activate
    Set Busca = WorkBookNovo.Application.Cells.Find(What:=valor, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Busca.Activate
    Busca_col = Busca.Column
    WorkBookNovo.ActiveSheet.Columns(Busca_col).Select
    numRows = Selection.Rows.Count
    Selection.Resize(numRows - 2).Select
    Selection.Offset(2, 0).Select
    Selection.Value = RangeFrom.Value
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1").Activate

    contador = contador + 1
   col = col + 1
Loop

MsgBox contador

End Sub
```

Se você quiser melhorar o desmpenho seria legal identificar a ultima linha para delimitar um range menor no lugar de `ActiveSheet.Columns(Busca_col).Select`

Comment: Obrigada Rubem, funcionou desta maneira. No entanto, são muitas colunas, e ele copia somente algumas, e algumas ele cola a mesma coluna repetida vezes. Tentei encontrar algum possível erro mas não consegui. Esqueci de comentar que ambas as planilhas possuem a primeira linha vazia, o indice na segunda linha e então os dados a partir da terceira linha, isso pode ser a causa do problema ? Estou aprendendo VBA por isso não sei exatamente ! Obrigada

Comment: Sim. Essa disposição diferente do cabeçalho das colunas não vai funcionar. Você deve fazer algumas alterações. 

1) A linha <code>ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1").Activate</code> no início do <code>Do While</code> deve ficar antes do início do bloco. Isso vai garantir que ele percorra a primeira linha da planilha origem.
2) No momento da colagem dos dados deve ser alterado o parâmetro <code>row</code> do método <code>Selection.Resize</code> e <code>Selection.Offset</code>.

Comment: Vou editar a resposta conforme essa explicação. Se lhe servir marque como resposta :-) .

Comment: Um recurso legal para você aprender é usar o depurador. Coloque uma bolinha vermelha clicando do lado da linha de código no ponto onde você quer que o código pare. Vai dando F8 e vendo o comportamento do código. Um segundo, grave macros e estude os códigos que o Excel gerou com o depurador. 

Foi desta forma que aprendi bastante quando trabalhava com VBA.